# Htpc connected to two rooms

Tags: windows-7, connection, tv, htpc

My setup is like this:
in the living room I have an htpc, plasma (vga and dvi connections directly to the htpc), reciever (connected via optic, no hdmi :( but connected to an awesome set of speakers). 
In the bedroom i have an LCD connected to the HTPC through HDMI with built in speakers. 
Considering i dont want both tvs to run simultanously, how should i set it up for easy switching? Apps wise and connection wise and configuration wise.

Thanks
I have win 7.

Comment: Are you looking for independent TVs, or the same video/audio on both screens?

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to grab an [HDMI Switcher](http://reviews.cnet.com/4321-7871_7-6602831.html) and then grabbing an [HDMI to DVI adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0018QTWH2) and connecting them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There's no performance loss outputing TV signal to both the HDMI and the optical fibre.

Keep both the LCD/TV off, then turn them on when you're in that room.

Are you trying to connect both with HDMI? Then you'll need some sort of [HDMI splitter](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hdmi+splitter).

If you're trying to accomplish something else, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just run a HDMI splitter which displays the same thing on 2 HDMI outputs from 1 input source. I have a 20m HDMI cable which works perfectly and didn't actually cost that much. It will simply display the same thing on both TVs, and you could turn on/off each TV without worrying about pressing any additional buttons etc. The splitter box I use is made by a company called 'Neet' and cost around £25